# Limited access to AWS S3 bucket: Wordpress links

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have a Wordpress based membership site using Academy theme, with content (video, downloadable XML and ZIP files, etc.) hosted on AWS. Some of this content is public, and some is member only, and I am trying to figure out a way to actually secure that member only content.

I know I can configure CloudFront to require a specific domain, so I looked in to having a members.website.com sub domain for signed in users, but the theme does not support this. Both signed in and not signed in pages have to use the same domain.

I am nearly certain that this is possible, either through signed URLs or signed cookies, but I can't seem to grok how to do this with Wordpress. Can anyone point me to a resource that covers this scenario? Or simply verify that this can't be done?

Answer (score 0):

This can most certainly be done, but as you said you're limited by your Wordpress theme as to what functionality could be required.

Firstly, my suggestion would be separating the S3 buckets, one for public and one for membership (easier to restrict the rulesets).

In your CloudFront distribution if you can create a secondary origin for a path such as `/membership` or `/restricted` and have that target your S3 bucket as the destination. By doing this it will all be on the same domain but will be resolving to isolated buckets depending on the path of the file.

If you set the cache behaviour for this specific origin to use trusted signers you can generate a [signed cookie](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html) from your application that would grant you access to the membership only origin.

If you're not able to add this logic into your Wordpress site then instead you could take the approach of using Lambda@Edge to determine if the user should be allowed access to this content.

AWS have published a [post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authorizationedge-how-to-use-lambdaedge-and-json-web-tokens-to-enhance-web-application-security/) specifically about using Lambda@Edge in this way.

Comment: Looks like I have some reading to do, and the secondary origins do seem like they have potential. However, right after that you mention "signed cookie from your application" and that's where I think it falls apart. there is no application. There is nothing but a web link. So how does one "generate a cookie" via <a href> or a video player short code?

Comment: The signed cookie needs to be generated via the SDK or CLI. For Wordpress this would mean a plugin would need to do this for you, so might require that to be developed if one does not exist.